# z index 1 doesn't stop modal from pushing down index 0 content

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, simplemodal

Hi all I have a modal that I made, I set it to have a z-index of 1 and the component its inside of has a `z-index` of 0 however the modal still stretches the component when it pops up even though it sits ontop of the content like you see in the image below

[image]

I would like to make the modal overlay without stretching this component down as it pushes all the other content down which I want to avoid I'm not sure of the best way to accomplish this because the component in purple is reused across multiple views inside my `vue router. I will show the code for my component :) any suggestions on how to accomplish this are appreciated

```
<template>
<div id="topbarContainer" v-bind:class="{ modalbackground: modal }">
<!-- TOPBAR -->
    <div class="topbar">

      <h6 id="dashboard">{{name}}</h6>

      <div class="searchContainer">
        <b-icon-search></b-icon-search>
        <small>search</small>
        <input class="searchbar" type="text" />
        <small class="searchbtn">H</small> 
      </div>
     
     <div id="topbarRightdiv">
      <img class="topbarButtons" src="../assets/superdash/chat-1.png" width="30px" height="30px" />
      <img class="topbarButtons" src="../assets/superdash/notifications.png" width="30px" height="30px" />
      <img class="topbarButtons" src="../assets/superdash/photo.png" width="30px" height="30px" />
      <p id="profileName" @click="showModal">Hemlin <small id="profileArrow">&#x25BC;</small></p>
    </div>

<!--modal -->

  <div  v-if="this.modal==true" class="modal-content">
      
        <section class="modalSection ModalsectionHeader">
        <img class="modalImg" src="../assets/topbar/profile_icons-2.svg"/> <p id="darkmodeText">Dark Mode</p> <img class="modalImg" src="../assets/topbar/togle.svg" @click="toggleDarkmode" v-if="darkmode==true"/> <img class="modalImg" src="../assets/topbar/togle.svg" @click="toggleDarkmode" v-if="darkmode==false"/> 
        </section>
        <section class="modalSection">
          <img class="modalImg" src="../assets/topbar/profile_icons.svg"/> <p>Profile</p> <small>&#62;</small>
        </section>
        <section class="modalSection">
          <img class="modalImg" src="../assets/topbar/profile_icons-1.svg"/> <p>Wallet</p> <small>&#62;</small>
        </section>
        <section class="modalSection">
          <img class="modalImg" src="../assets/topbar/profile_icons-3.svg"/> <p>Saved</p> <small>&#62;</small>
        </section>
        <section class="modalSection">
          <img class="modalImg" src="../assets/topbar/profile_icons-4.svg"/> <p>Get Reports</p> <small>&#62;</small>
        </section>

    </div>
      
    </div>
<!-- TOPBAR -->
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Topbar',
  props: ['name'],
  
  data:function(){
  return{
    modal: false,
    darkmode: false,
  }
},
methods:{
    showModal(){
      console.log("clicked")
      this.modal = !this.modal
    }
    ,toggleDarkmode(){
      console.log('darkmode')
      this.darkmode = !this.darkmode
    }
  }
}

</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
#topbarContainer{
  z-index: 0;
}
.modalbackground{
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.555);
}
.topbar{
  display: flex;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}
#topbarRightdiv{
display: flex;
margin-left: 9em;
}

#topbarRightdiv p{
display: flex;
}

#profileName{
 font-size:14px;
 padding-top: 1em;
}
#profileName:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
}
#profileArrow{
  color: #39b3fac5;
}
#profileArrow:hover{
  color: #39d3fa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#dashboard{
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 5em;
}

.searchContainer{
 margin-top:1em;
 margin-left: 1em;
 margin-right:3em;
 width: 60%;
 border-style: none;
 border-radius: 13px;
 background-color: white;
 height: 2em;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #88888877;
}

.searchbar{
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 13px;
  width: 85%;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.searchbtn{
  margin-left: .5em;
  color: rgb(73, 79, 90);
  border-left: 1px rgb(185, 187, 204) solid;
  padding-left:1em;
}

.topbarButtons{
 margin: 1em;
 border-radius: 100%;
 background-color: #87b9fa1a;
}






/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
  width: 30em;
  height: 20em;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
.modalSection{
  padding-top: .5em;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.ModalsectionHeader{
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(97, 95, 95, 0.267);
}
#darkmodeText{
  margin: .2em
}
.modalImg{
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the position to absolute :

```
.modal-content {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative; <---HERE to absolute
```

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#demo',
  props: ['name'],
  
  data:function(){
  return{
    modal: false,
    darkmode: false,
  }
},
methods:{
    showModal(){
      console.log("clicked")
      this.modal = !this.modal
    },
    toggleDarkmode(){
      console.log('darkmode')
      this.darkmode = !this.darkmode
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#topbarContainer{
  z-index: 0;
}
.modalbackground{
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.555);
}
.topbar{
  display: flex;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}
#topbarRightdiv{
display: flex;
margin-left: 9em;
}

#topbarRightdiv p{
display: flex;
}

#profileName{
 font-size:14px;
 padding-top: 1em;
}
#profileName:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
}
#profileArrow{
  color: #39b3fac5;
}
#profileArrow:hover{
  color: #39d3fa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#dashboard{
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 5em;
}

.searchContainer{
 margin-top:1em;
 margin-left: 1em;
 margin-right:3em;
 width: 60%;
 border-style: none;
 border-radius: 13px;
 background-color: white;
 height: 2em;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #88888877;
}

.searchbar{
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 13px;
  width: 85%;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.searchbtn{
  margin-left: .5em;
  color: rgb(73, 79, 90);
  border-left: 1px rgb(185, 187, 204) solid;
  padding-left:1em;
}

.topbarButtons{
 margin: 1em;
 border-radius: 100%;
 background-color: #87b9fa1a;
}






/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  width: 30em;
  height: 20em;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;

}
.modalSection{
  padding-top: .5em;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.ModalsectionHeader{
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(97, 95, 95, 0.267);
}
#darkmodeText{
  margin: .2em
}
.modalImg{
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<div id="topbarContainer" v-bind:class="{ modalbackground: modal }">
<!-- TOPBAR -->
    <div class="topbar">

      <h6 id="dashboard">{{name}}</h6>

      <div class="searchContainer">
        <b-icon-search></b-icon-search>
        <small>search</small>
        <input class="searchbar" type="text" />
        <small class="searchbtn">H</small> 
      </div>
     
     <div id="topbarRightdiv">
      <img class="topbarButtons" src="https://picsum.photos/30" width="30px" height="30px" />
      <img class="topbarButtons" src="https://picsum.photos/30" width="30px" height="30px" />
      <img class="topbarButtons" src="https://picsum.photos/30" width="30px" height="30px" />
      <p id="profileName" @click="showModal">Hemlin <small id="profileArrow">&#x25BC;</small></p>
    </div>

<!--modal -->

  <div  v-if="this.modal==true" class="modal-content">
      
        <section class="modalSection ModalsectionHeader">
        <img class="modalImg" src="https://picsum.photos/30"/> <p id="darkmodeText">Dark Mode</p> <img class="modalImg" src="https://picsum.photos/30" @click="toggleDarkmode" v-if="darkmode==true"/> <img class="modalImg" src="https://picsum.photos/30" @click="toggleDarkmode" v-if="darkmode==false"/> 
        </section>
        <section class="modalSection">
          <img class="modalImg" src="https://picsum.photos/30"/> <p>Profile</p> <small>&#62;</small>
        </section>
        <section class="modalSection">
          <img class="modalImg" src="https://picsum.photos/30"/> <p>Wallet</p> <small>&#62;</small>
        </section>
        <section class="modalSection">
          <img class="modalImg" src="https://picsum.photos/30"/> <p>Saved</p> <small>&#62;</small>
        </section>
        <section class="modalSection">
          <img class="modalImg" src="https://picsum.photos/30"/> <p>Get Reports</p> <small>&#62;</small>
        </section>

    </div>
      
    </div>
<!-- TOPBAR -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah yea thanks :D ofcourse I missed it but that fixed it right up

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on writing  toggleDarkMode(), you wrote ,toggleDarkMode(). Move up the comma (,).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).